# Peer channel join using the REST API (sample application) fails saying FORBIDDEN at the nodejs terminal

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running the sample app and trying to join a channel using REST APIs.

The following error happens at a place when the `channel.getgenesisblock(request)` call is being made.

The GitHUB code is at ["Handson-Blockchain-Development-with-Hyperledger"](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Handson-Blockchain-Development-with-Hyperledger/blob/master/middleware/join-channel.js)

But I am kind of lost on how to approach the problem.
I get the following error on the blockchain terminal:

> peer0.utilityorg.utility.com     | 2018-07-24 22:48:45.194 UTC
>   [gossip/discovery] periodicalSendAlive -> DEBU 242 Sleeping 5s
>   orderer.utility.com              | 2018-07-24 22:48:47.050 UTC
>   [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 011 [channel: utilitychannel]
>   **Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 172.18.0.1:56912: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied**
>   orderer.utility.com              | 2018-07-24 22:48:47.080 UTC
>   [common/deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 012 [channel: utilitychannel]
>   Client authorization revoked for deliver request from 172.18.0.1:56916:
>   Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining:
>   permission denied

And at the `node.js` server terminal:

> error: [Orderer.js]: sendDeliver - rejecting - status:FORBIDDEN
>   **Error: Invalid results returned ::FORBIDDEN
>       at ClientDuplexStream. (/home/node_modules/fabric-**client/lib/Orderer.js:231:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

The `curl` command passes without any errors:

```
hypledvm@hypledvm-VirtualBox:~/go/src/utilitypoc$ curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/channel/join -H "authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MzI0NzY2MDksInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJvcmdOYW1lIjoidXRpbGl0eW9yZyIsImlhdCI6MTUzMjQ3MjQ2OX0.9Jo58NXkIbsQbJ7wtw4-WtctgUo8m0fPqmvn_WHLfPg"
```

it does return

> {"success":true,"message":"Channel joined"}

Related to the error - I have the following questions:

1. Why does the FORBIDDEN error and permission denied occur?
2. I login in to the peer docker container and try to do peer channel join (assuming peer channel create already worked), it expects a genesis block which i don't see inside the peer container. Is it the way it should be?
3. I created the channel.tx and genesis.block using configtxgen tool before running the nodejs sample app.
4. How do I change the policies in channel.tx (on inspectChannelTx) or where is it written from?
5. The constants.js specifies some policies - is that relevant to this scenario? (I have modified my application from the same to have two orgs where one of the orgs is the admin) - https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Handson-Blockchain-Development-with-Hyperledger/blob/master/middleware/constants.js**

Any pointers would be helpful.
Please let me know if I need to elaborate somewhere.